# Do We need connection pool for redis client

Tags: ruby, redis, sidekiq

Redis is single threaded so do we need to setup connection pool for our redis client apps? I see several libraries use connection pool for redis such as sidekiq, but does it really needed?

Answer (score 0):

Redis server is single threaded. It makes a lot of sense to keep it busy with clients sending multiple requests instead of blocking by making a single request at a time.